# Is this edit valid?

Tags: discussion

I think not, but since I didn't find any way of flagging it, I'll just post it here. The edit in question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24294644/2), the corresponding question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294578/log10-0-can-compile-but-log0-0-cannot). In short, the answer says "This will not work because x=y", while the edit replaces it with "x=z". It does not ultimately matter for the answer whether x=y or x=z, so it is not a major edit, but I'd say still a nontrivial one.

In the comments of that answer, someone actually asks "Shouldn't it be `-Inf` (x=z) not `NaN` (x=y)? And **the answer poster himself** comments "That's implementation dependent".

I find it inappropriate (rude?) to evade the discussion in the comments by just editing it into the answer. Also, I guess that robo editers would just approve anything that is there. If you think the answer is technically wrong and you see that the poster doesn't agree with you, downvote it instead of enforcing the change..

Comment: It may not be rudeness, it may simply be ignorance. The person who submitted the edit might not have seen the comment reply. And while there are plenty of bad reviewers, this isn't necessarily bad reviewing. They cannot see the comments when they're reviewing edits. They'd have to click through to see the answer and read them themselves...and with no indication that they should, it's unlikely anyone would.

Comment: The editor may also think the result of `log(0.0)` is *not* implementation-dependent, as there is no reference to back the comment. Our [currently preferred C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) says it returns `-Inf`, but the question is tagged `[c]`, so... who knows.

Comment: Even if so, as I said - don't edit an answer against the explicit wish of the answerer. If you think this is relevant, downvote it.

Comment: I do think you are right to question an edit that changes the technical meaning of a post, without the OP being on board with that change. And I don't think that edit was really appropriate; but I don't think it goes to the level of being explicitly rude. Perhaps the editor just thinks that was appropriate.

Comment: Its something that really should be a comment, even if the edit in question is correct. Probably the person who answered is just being stubborn... Neither party here is right.

Comment: Note that in many languages, there is a difference between `x=y` and `y=x` — automatic type casting can change the outcome depending which variable comes first. I'm not sure if it matters with C, but I think it might, for example if x is an int and y is a float.

Answer (score 30):

The fact that the author of the post *specifically* rejected the suggestion in comments makes this case crystal clear.  We don't need to make any assumptions at all about what the authors intentions may have been, because he has specifically told us that in this case he very clearly intended to write what he did, and does not want his post to say what it was edited to say, as such editing it is entirely inappropriate, and should not have been approved.  Rolling back the edit is also appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Reject edit dialog]

- Is it plagiarism? No. Nobody ever uses that reason (for posts, not wikis).
- Is it incorrect? Meh, can't tell in 2 seconds, next.
- Does it change the intention of the post? Maybe, can't tell in 2 seconds. It definitely changes it more than just clarifying or formatting. Therefore it is an **invalid edit**.
- Too minor? Not really…
- Vandalism? No.

Matched a reason, should be rejected.

It is the burden of the editor to convince the reviewers that it's correct. "NAN should be -Inf" Why? The edit summary would work as a comment tho.

Comment: The plagiarism reason, I believe, appears only for tag wiki suggestions. And for those, I *frequently* use that reason. I encourage others to do so as well.

Comment: @CodyGray No, thats for post edits. And I'm talking about post edits. Of course it's a lot more useful for tag wikis.

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn that it used to be shown conditionally for tag wiki edits. I wonder if that's a regression bug or an intentional change? (The regression bug could conceivably be against either the SE codebase or my brain.)

Comment: I think you meant to say it is a **radical change**, given your explanation.

Comment: @Joe A radical change is a fundamental change in meaning or intent. I don't know if it is, I don't know c. But it is changing enough that it should be a *comment* not edit, so it's an *invalid exit*.

Comment: You went down the list of reasons, said "Meh, can't tell" to invalid edit, and said "definitely" to the radical change reason.  Hence, in your explanation, you should be saying **radical change**.  (Additionally, I agree that it probably should be radical change; invalid edit should mean "it's actually wrong", while radical change is "it may be right, but it's not what the author meant", which is exactly what happened here: the author said Y, this edit says Z, both may or may not be right but author specifically wanted Y.)

Comment: @Joe Well, I guess you have a different interpretation of the reasons. Anyway, the important thing is that it gets rejected.